# Is it the best way to optimize this SQL statement when using not in in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

The table called `TB_ORDER` have 90 million records of data,but only have 500 records which STATE is neither B nor C.

```
SELECT 
    ORDER.ID,ORDER.STATE,ORDER.NAME 
FROM 
    TB_ORDER ORDER 
WHERE 
    ORDER.STATE NOT IN ('B','C') ;
```

My workmate writes the sql like this and it cost about 7 minites because of `full table scan`.So I try to change it like this.Its that OK?I have add index on state field. Is  it still `full table scan` because the subquery sql result is very large((90000000-500)/90000000)?

```
SELECT 
    A.ID,A.NAME,A.STATE 
FROM TB_ORDER A 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1 FROM TB_ORDER B WHERE A.ID=B.ID and B.STATE='B'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 FROM TB_ORDER C WHERE A.ID=C.ID and C.STATE='C'
        )
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Do they give the same results?  Subselects are almost always slower than not.  If you can, avoid them.

Comment: Excluding only 500 records from 90 million records will always take time. You might trying partitioning the table.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai,the real  result what I want is only 500 records from total result.

Comment: The first version is fine.  A full table scan is necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,No,it runs so slowly,So my boss ask me to optimize it.

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select ... rest of your query` and then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)` then copy a result of last query (as a text !!! not bitmap) and paste it to the question.

Comment: @krokodilko is right. Check the explain plan. My experience with Oracle 11 and beyond is that two very different looking SQL statements that do the same thing end up with the same explain plan. Have you run statistics on the table? Depending upon a lot of factors I won't go into here, that can make a huge difference. Adding an index for state could help, but only if  state "B'" and "C" aren't a large percentage of the records. Oracle may choose to do a full table scan anyway. Learn how to use explain plan, it is the key to improving SQL performance.

Comment: Can you make changes to the table? What are the other distinct order states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the NOT IN ? You could work around that by using a function and then creating a function based index. Make sure you where clause matches the predicate exactly. Example:

```
-- table
create table t_large_table (id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,state VARCHAR2(1));
-- some sample data
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    INSERT INTO t_large_table (state) VALUES ('A');
    INSERT INTO t_large_table (state) VALUES ('B');
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO t_large_table (state) VALUES ('C');
  INSERT INTO t_large_table (state) VALUES ('D');
  COMMIT;
END;
/

-- create index with function that has a bucket to put all states that are relevant to me. In this case everything that is not A or B
CREATE INDEX t_large_table_idx 
  ON t_large_table (CASE state WHEN 'A' THEN 'A' WHEN 'B' THEN 'B' ELSE 'X' END);

-- run a select with exactly same function as the index
SELECT * 
  FROM t_large_table
 WHERE CASE state WHEN 'A' THEN 'A' WHEN 'B' THEN 'B' ELSE 'X' END = 'X';

-- check explain plan
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                   |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T_LARGE_TABLE     |
|   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | T_LARGE_TABLE_IDX |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a suggestion, you may try.

```
Select o.ID,o.o,o.NAME 
FROM TB_ORDER o
Inner Join
(
 Select STATE  from
 (
  Select STATE from TB_ORDER Group by ORDER 
 ) Q Where STATE NOT IN ('B','C') 
) QQ on QQ.STATE = o.STATE
```